# Windows WSL2 docker.exe volume mount differs from wsl docker volume mounts

Tags: docker, wsl-2

I got Docker Desktop installed on Windows with WSL2 support. Everything works as expected. When I run my containers with a volume mount `docker run -it --rm -v W:\projects:/projects busybox` i can access all my windows files inside this folder.

Sadly the performance isn't that great with windows shares inside docker, so i tried to mount a path from my wsl machine.

i was under the impression that docker would run inside wsl? So I expected the two commands to output the same:

```
docker run -it --rm -v /home/:/myHome busybox ls -l /myHome
wsl docker run -it --rm -v /home/:/myHome busybox ls -l /myHome
```

but the output using `docker` is just `total 0` where as the output using `wsl` is my home directory.

Can someone explain to me where this `/home` directory is (physically / in wsl / my computer) when I run `docker` from windows? And is it possible to run `docker` and it runs `wsl docker` without symlinks / path modifications so i can mount my linux directory inside the container?

Answer (score 2):

If `wsl-2` is installed, you can access its file system by going to the following path :-

```
\\wsl$
```

`/home` wouldn't just work as its not physically present in Windows's file system

**You can however use `/home` or any other linux based directories if you login to your wsl distro. Please note that the following command won't mount any volumes if you run it from windows. It should be run only from your wsl distro**

```
docker run --name mycontainer -v /home:myhome busybox
```

**To access the `/home` directory in an `Ubuntu-16.04` distro from windows:-**

```
\\wsl$\Ubuntu-16.04\home
```

You can replace `Ubuntu-16.04` with your `distro name - version`

To mount any of the directories which is under wsl, ensure that you have turned on the option "Enable integration with my default wsl distro"
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/

To mount a `wsl`'s directory from windows as a volume, provide your host volume path in the given format

```
docker run --name mycontainer -v \\wsl$\Ubuntu-16.04\home:/myHome busybox
```

**Basically, `docker run -v` has an effect from which environment its being executed i.e either windows or wsl**

And docker volumes are present in the following path if you have enabled wsl-2 for docker but don't want to use your distro's file system

```
\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\version-pack-data\community\docker\volumes\
```

Comment: Yes but where is `/home` when i run `docker run -v /home:/myHome busybox` ? And why isnt it the same as `wsl docker run ...`

Comment: what wsl distro are you currently using? and also ensure that you have enabled 
integration with your default wsl distro
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/